# Simple Javascript not working to hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to learn a little bit of java script, an any help would be greatly appreciated as I am pretty new to this world and just learning. I have tried looking up and down this site and have tried several suggestions from other users but none really seem to answer my issue.

I have this bit of code:

Im simply trying to get it to slowly hide a div box when the x is clicked. the button shows up and can be clicked but nothing happens. can someone help me out and show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<div id="daily_deal">
    <button id="close_x" onclick="myFunction($)"><img src="/assets/templates/blacbold_TEST/images/red_x.png" /></button>
    <div id="widget"><iframe src="dailydeal_widget.asp" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"     style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:155px; height:355px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></div>
```

```
  function myFunction($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#close_x").click(function () {
              $("#widget").slideToggle("slow");
          });
      });
  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: +1 for providing code and HTML... Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<button id="close_x" onclick="toggleWidget();">
```

and

```
function toggleWidget() {
    $("#widget").slideToggle("slow");
}
```

Comment: Given a choice of mixing JQuery *and* function calls in HTML, and using JQuery only, I would always recommend a JQuery only approach (simplifies maintenance).

Comment: Thank you all for the help. Here is the link to he site if you'ld like to take a look. it's the daily deal widget on the right hand side. any design or functionality sugestions would be greatly appreciated. 

www.provisual.com

Comment: Roy. I used your approach to get my box to closer and open. i wanted to know something though. I have this <div> set up on the main frame of my website (header/footer etc...), so everytime that you click on a link the box resets and shows up again. is there a way to tell my site to keep the box closed always until the person clicks again to open it?

Answer (score 3):

You only need this bit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#close_x").click(function () {
          $("#widget").slideToggle("slow");
      });
  });
```

And then you can remove the `onclick` from the button:

```
<button id="close_x"><img src="/assets/templates/blacbold_TEST/images/red_x.png" /></button>
```

What it was doing is binding to the document ready event when you clicked the button, but as this has already happened the code that binds the click event is never run.

Comment: +1: Several identical answers, but you got there first with a clear explanation and example.

Comment: "but as this has already happened the code that binds the click event is never run." the pseudo event document ready use a promise resolved manually even DOM is already ready. Document ready can then be used at any time, just handler is unbound once fired. That's said +1 for explanation

Comment: Thank you all for the help. Here is the link to he site if you'ld like to take a look. it's the daily deal widget on the right hand side. any design or functionality suggestions would be greatly appreciated. 

www.provisual.com

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `$(document).ready()` row. That is, remove line 2 and 6 from your function. It's implying that you want to do something when page has loaded, which will not occur at the same time as this function is called.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. Here is the link to he site if you'ld like to take a look. it's the daily deal widget on the right hand side. any design or functionality suggestions would be greatly appreciated. 

www.provisual.com

Answer (score 0):

You only need this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#close_x").on("click", function () {
          $("#widget").slideToggle("slow");
      });
  });
```

the `onclick="myFunction($)"` is not neccessary anymore.

Comment: THANK YOU EVERYONE! it works perfectly I really appreciate all of the help. God Bless

Answer (score 0):

No need to call function in onclick, so your resultant html should be like this.

```
<button id="close_x"><img src="/assets/templates/blacbold_TEST/images/red_x.png" /></button>
```

And your script should be

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#close_x").click(function () {
              $("#widget").slideToggle("slow");
          });
      });
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help. Here is the link to he site if you'ld like to take a look. it's the daily deal widget on the right hand side. any design or functionality sugestions would be greatly appreciated. 

www.provisual.com

Answer (score 0):

you can try this function for hide and show div tag:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $(".productDescription").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".productDescription").slideToggle();
return false;
});
```

});

Like HtmL Code:

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide">See Full Description</a>
<div class="productDescription">
  <p>This very large bath bomb will fizz up to two minutes, how good is that. Drizzled   with soap it looks so authentic. This cake slice has a scent of Tropical Fruit including   Pineapple, Mango & Grapefruit and you'll be surrounded by gorgeous flowers and glitter.   <a  href="#" class="show_hide">Hide</a></p></div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help. Here is the link to he site if you'ld like to take a look. it's the daily deal widget on the right hand side. any design or functionality sugestions would be greatly appreciated. 

www.provisual.com